# Variável não recebe novo valor

Tags: c#, unity3d

Tenho um objeto que deve ficar "caindo" sobre a tela várias vezes, e isso funciona.

O que estou tentando fazer é com que uma variável chamada x receba mais 1 sempre que este objeto passar pela tela. Quando x receber mais 5, quero que outra variável chamada y receba menos 1.

Para isso declarei ambas variáveis e atribuí um valor a elas: x = 0 e y = 5.

**PROBLEMA:**

x deveria receber mais 1 quando o objeto passasse pela tela, e isto acontece, porém apenas uma vez. Quando o objeto passa pela primeira vez pela tela, x recebe mais 1, mas após isso, x para no 1 e não recebe mais nada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para y receber menos 1, x deve receber 5, então creio que esse é o motivo para que y não mude o valor, já que x não passa de 1.

Nenhuma mensagem de erro é exibida durante a execução do jogo.

Por que o valor da variável x não muda?

**CÓDIGO:**

```
private int x, y;

void Start() {
    x = 0;
    y = 5;
}

void OnBecameInvisible() {
    // quando o objeto passar pela tela
    x += 1;
    Debug.Log("Valor de x: " + x);

    if ((x % 5) == 0)
    {
        // sempre que x receber mais 5
        y -= 1;
        Debug.Log("Valor de y: " + y);
    }
}
```

**Observação:** não coloquei todo o código porque o restante dele é sobre a velocidade que o objeto irá cair, posição e coisas do tipo.

Comment: Nós precisamos entender o que está acontecendo.  Pra mim tá tudo certo aí, não vejo problemas. Você tem que mostrar o problema acontecendo. Leia como fazer um [mcve]

Comment: Como eu disse na pergunta, o problema é que o valor de ambas variáveis não mudam. Em OnBecameInvisible(), depois de x receber mais 1 a variável tem o seu valor imprimido, e como pode ver no código, a mesma coisa acontece com a variável y. Não é exibido nenhuma mensagem de erro durante a execução do jogo, então é difícil saber o porque disso!

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta e tentar deixar isso mais claro.

Answer (score 0):

Tente alterar o nome do objeto que está passando sobre a tela toda vez que ativar a função OnBecame. Pode ser uma possível solução. Poderá fazer o teste jogando dois objetos na tela e observando se a variavel X recebe uma soma.